# How do I make CSS :active styles work on trackpad taps?

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, pseudo-class

Most trackpads on laptops have a tap-to-click option/feature where light taps are recognized as presses (either pressing one of the trackpad buttons or pressing down on the trackpad surface on buttonless trackpads) and trigger a click. I've noticed on my Macbook Pro that CSS `:active` styles aren't applied to HTML elements if I *tap* on my trackpad; they're only applied if I *press down* on the trackpad and it clicks.

Is there a way to make trackpad taps (not mobile touchscreen taps) trigger the `:active` state?

Comment: my trackpad (macbook) with a simple tap - not pressing - does cause the `:active` pseudo-state to be applied

Comment: See [How to pass css :active pseudo class to javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966288/how-to-pass-css-active-pseudo-class-to-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Touch pad taps and clicks are processed by the operating system and/or the browser. There isn't a way to register Clicks between Taps through CSS or JS. For example: @danyamachine said it works on his MacBook, this is most likely because he was using a different browser that handles clicks vs taps differently.