# How to pass css :active pseudo class to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Reference: [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964831/cannot-get-parent-element-using-jquery/39965260?noredirect=1#comment67210576_39964831) posted by @AnkithAmtange

---

Given html

```
<div>Click Away</div>
```

css

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
div:active {
  color: white;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u3uhq9m1/

How to pass the currently [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:active) pseudo class `DOM` element to `javascript`?

First attempt. Note, jQuery is not a requirement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var active;
  $("div").click(function() {
    active = $(":active");
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("active", active)
    }, 1000)
  }) 
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u3uhq9m1/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `document.activeElement` for that.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', function() {
    console.log(document.activeElement);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">asdf</div>
<span>123</span>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
<button>123</button>
<input />
```

### Update

If you want to pass the current `:active` element - you must use the `mousedown` (and not the `click` event), because the `:active` element is not active anymore once your mouse is up.

Since the `:active` bubbles up the DOM tree, all the parent elements will also get the `:active` pseudo-class (added a red border in the following example) so I took only the last element in the `$(':active')` selector.

Check this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var active;
  $(document).mousedown(function() {
    active = $(":active");
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("active", active.last()[0])
    }, 1000)
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange
}
div:active {
  color: white;
  background: rebeccapurple
}
:active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Click Away</div>
```

Comment: Clicking `#a`, `span` elements logs `<body>` at `console`, instead of `#a`, `span` elements.  [Document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement) _"Returns the currently focused element, that is, the element that will get keystroke events if the user types any"_ , _"When there is no selection, the active element is the page's `<body>` or null"_

Comment: If you want the "clicked" element you can just use `event.toElement` inside `$(document).on('click'`

Comment: _"If you want the "clicked" element you can just use `event.toElement`"_  `event.toElement` logs `undefined`at firefox 45, `event.originalEvent.explicitOriginalTarget` logs clicked node. Requirement of Question is to pass `css` [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:active) pseudo class to `javascript`. Are you suggesting that `DOM` `click` event is equivalent to `css` `:active` pseudo class?

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize `:active:hover` pseudo class, `animation` with `duration` set to `0s`, `@keyframes` at `css`; `animationend` event at `javascript`

```css
:root {
  --activeprop: 0px;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  left: var(--activeprop);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
div:active:hover {
  color: white;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  animation: active 0s;
  -moz-animation: active 0s;
  -webkit-animation: active 0s;
}

@keyframes active {
  from {
    left:var(--activeprop);
  }
  to {
    left:var(--activeprop);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes active {
  from {
    left:var(--activeprop);
  }
  to {
    left:var(--activeprop);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes active {
  from {
    left:var(--activeprop);
  }
  to {
    left:var(--activeprop);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Click Away</div>
<script>
for (el of document.querySelectorAll("div")) {
el.addEventListener("animationend", function(event) {
  console.log(`${event.target.nodeName} is :active`)
})
};
</script>
```