# How can I determine what elements have an inactive selection in a page with multiple browsing contexts (parent, iframe, optionally more iframes)?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

The [`document.activeElement` attribute:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement)

> Returns the currently focused element, that is, the element that will get keystroke events if the user types any

This is clear for a single browsing context (single document + window). If a focusable element (input, textarea contenteditable element) has a visible selection, it will be the `document.activeElement` element.

When you have one or more iframes on the page and they have focusable elements, the behavior changes.

If an input in an iframe is focused, the parent document’s `activeElement` property will point to that iframe’s iframe element (the actual `<iframe>` node). However, any previously selected text in focusable elements will stay visibly selected, though it visually appears inactive (greyed-out):

[image: focused iframe input]

If you then focus back to the input in the parent document, the iframe’s input will no longer be the iframe document’s `activeElement`, and it will also appear visibly selected though inactive:

[image: focused parent input]

How can I check for any focusable elements in a `document` with a visible selection, even when it isn’t the document’s `activeElement`?

---

**Edit**

I’ve made a demo playground to illustrate the behavior: http://codepen.io/acusti/pen/PGakzY?editors=0010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@guest271314](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2801559/guest271314) pointed me in the right direction for solving this issue. As illustrated in [this demo](http://codepen.io/acusti/pen/PGakzY?editors=0010), using `document.getSelection()` allows you to find any focusable elements in a browsing context with a visible selection, even when they are “inactive” because a different browsing context (or another browser window or part of the browser) is active. The `getSelection()` API does require a bit of extra logic to deal with the different kind of things it can return. But for the purposes of identifying a selection with a focusable element (input, textarea), after using `document.getSelection()` and then checking `anchorNode` in the returned selection object for `childNodes && childNodes.length`, you can reliably get the element with the selection by accessing `selection.anchorNode.childNodes[selection.anchorOffset]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `.activeElement` or selection in an array; for example at an event, then select the element or selection at index `array.length - 2` of the array.

See also [How to clear the contents of an iFrame from another iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645685/how-to-clear-the-contents-of-an-iframe-from-another-iframe/) , [How to pass css :active pseudo class to javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966288/how-to-pass-css-active-pseudo-class-to-javascript/)

Comment: Sigh. I’m hoping there’s another way. Caching the previous activeElement isn’t a reliable way to determine if the selection is still visible. For example, if you are in an iframe and have a selection in an input, then click to a separate iframe's input, the selection will still be visible (but appear inactive). However, if you click from the selected input to the body of the *same* iframe, the selection will no longer be visible. For both, iframe’s document.activeElement will have gone from being the input with selected text to the iframe’s body, with no way to tell the difference.

Comment: @AndrewPatton See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169786/clear-text-selection-with-javascript

Comment: So `window.getSelection` was in fact the missing piece! It will return the “inactive” visible selection in a browsing context. Now I need to figure out how to use `document.selection.createRange` as my fallback. If you’d like to make an answer (or edit your existing one) using window.getSelection, I’d be happy to accept it, or else I’ll make one myself. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewPatton Perhaps posting an Answer to your own Question would be best way to convey what you have found using `window.getSelection`  and the approach that you are describing which resolved Question.